# MySQL GENERATED ALWAYS AS ... VIRTUAL syntax error on import

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax

Trying to import table from backup to another server and getting error in SQL syntax

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `book` (
  `bid` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `bookdate` datetime NOT NULL,
  `create_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `bookdate_date` date GENERATED ALWAYS AS (cast(`bookdate` as date)) VIRTUAL,
  `create_date_date` date GENERATED ALWAYS AS (cast(`create_date` as date)) VIRTUAL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`bid`),
  KEY `IDX_book_bookdate_date` (`bookdate_date`),
  KEY `IDX_book_create_date_date` (`create_date_date`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=316;
```

phpMyAminError

```
 #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GENERATED ALWAYS AS (cast(`bookdate` as date)) VIRTUAL,
  `create_date_date` da' at line 5
```

How do i fix import error? I dont know what this means its beyond my paygrade

```
  `bookdate_date` date GENERATED ALWAYS AS (cast(`bookdate` as date)) VIRTUAL,
  `create_date_date` date GENERATED ALWAYS AS (cast(`create_date` as date)) VIRTUAL,
```

Answer (score 2):

Those are [generated columns](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-generated-columns.html). They are set *automatically*, so you cannot assign values in an `insert` or `update`.  These were introduced in some version of MySQL 5.7, so older versions do not support them.  You can replace the idea using views, for similar functionality.

They are calculated -- using the expression -- when the table is queried.  This is convenient, because the value is always correct.  The `VIRTUAL` means that the column value is not stored in the table.

The alternative to `VIRTUAL` is `STORED`.  That calculates the value once when the row is inserted or updated.  It uses up storage space but can be convenient if the calculation is expensive.

EDIT:

Based on your comment, you have a problem.  One method is to create a view but that can be tricky.  Assuming that existing code is referencing the columns, your best best is to define the generated columns as regular columns and use triggers (`insert` and `update`) to set them.

Comment: @ZafaKonan . . . Presumably, you are using an old version of MySQL.  They have been supported for several years, but not before MySQL 5.7.

Comment: Yeah, its on GoDaddy hosting  surprised they not updated to 5.7 its still version 5.6.47-cll-lve

Any way to modify this Table to make compatible with old version of MySQL?